# Distinct values with Q objects

Tags: python, django

I have this query on my Django project 1.10.1 on Python 3:

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(subject=topic.id) | Q(object=topic.id) | Q(place=topic.id))
```

How can I prevent to get two identical `Event` records?

Comment: That query shouldn't give duplicate events. If an event has `subject=topic.id` and `object=topic.id`, it will only appear once in the queryset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) operator:

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(subject=topic.id) | Q(object=topic.id) | Q(place=topic.id)).distinct()
```

From the documentation:

> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d use distinct().

Make special note of their "However" clause before implementing this unless you expect to actually see duplicate results.

Comment: The issue with distinct in Django is that it no longer allows ordering of the results :(

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that query can ever give duplicate results.

I just tried a similar query on my similar setup, it will convert to an SQL query which looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM event 
WHERE (subject=x OR object=x OR place=x)
```

This will not duplicate any rows, so you don't actually need to do anything to avoid duplicate records.

Comment: I don't think this deserved to be downvoted. Saying that the query will not duplicate rows is better than adding `distinct()` to the queryset when it's not necessary.